# What does "[-14]" mean in the output from "aptitude safe-upgrade"?

Tags: aptitude

After `aptitude safe-upgrade` finishes running, it outputs something like this:

```
Current status: 0 updates [-14].
```

What does the "[-14]" mean?

Comment: See also [aptitude current status warning](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71019/aptitude-current-status-warning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is the number of packages that has been upgraded. Did you see the something like below at the confirmation prompt:

```
14 packages upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 230 MB/231 MB of archives. After unpacking 187 MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?]
```